# Yii get user by id

Tags: php, yii

I am creating  a widget where the userlist is only returning me as the members, and not finding the user by the ID supplied.

This is on HumHub based on Yii.

```
    <?php
        foreach($members as $member) {
            echo 'Searching for user: ' . $member['user_id'] . '<br />';
            $spaceUser = User::model()->find($member['user_id']);
    ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $spaceUser->getProfileUrl(); ?>"> 
            <img src="<?php echo $spaceUser->getProfileImage()->getUrl(); ?>" class="media-object space-widget-member-image img-rounded pull-left" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;" alt="24x24" data-src="holder.js/24x24" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" 
            data-original-title="<strong><?php echo $spaceUser->displayName; ?></strong><br><?php echo $spaceUser->profile->title; ?>" />
        </a>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Outputs

```
Searching for user: 1
Searching for user: 2
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMs43.png

Comment: explain your problem

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. And the problem was explained. the id supplied was not returning the user in question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get your result form your **USER** model like this way using `findByPk()` method if your model contain primary key

```
$spaceUser = User::model()->findByPk($member['user_id']));
```

Which will find a member based on the $member['user_id'] supplied.By the way,
your used `findByAttributes()` method is also good one to get result based on attribute.

See more: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findByPk-detail

Answer (score 0):

I was not using the correct function.

```
$spaceUser = User::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$member['user_id']));
```

Which will find a member based on the attributes supplied.

Comment: if id is primary key your USER model, then you can just User::model()->findByPk($member['user_id']);

Comment: Is that what Pk means. :) Thank you very much. Write an answer, I'll accept.